# Como validar qual modo de transação está sendo utilizado? (AspectJ / Proxy)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj

No momento, estamos construindo um módulo no Spring Boot que usa configurações de um legado, construído sobre o Spring MVC e possui muitas configurações (XML e classes).

Depois de algumas semanas, conseguimos compatibilizar o Spring Boot com as configurações legadas, mas não pudemos validar se, de fato, o AspectJ está funcionando como esperado.

**E por que digo isso?**

Nós observamos que durante a configuração, dentro do `TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector` (no código abaixo), estamos recebendo os `adviceModes` de `PROXY` e `ASPECTJ`:

```
/**
 * Returns {@link ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration} or
 * {@code AspectJ(Jta)TransactionManagementConfiguration} for {@code PROXY}
 * and {@code ASPECTJ} values of {@link EnableTransactionManagement#mode()},
 * respectively.
 */
@Override
protected String[] selectImports(AdviceMode adviceMode) {
    switch (adviceMode) {
        case PROXY:
            return new String[] {AutoProxyRegistrar.class.getName(),
                    ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class.getName()};
        case ASPECTJ:
            return new String[] {determineTransactionAspectClass()};
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Este caso em particular é ainda mais curioso, já que durante a depuração recebemos **duas vezes ASPECTJ** e **uma vez PROXY** no final das configurações. Parece que as configurações do AspectJ do legado estão sendo aplicadas, mas algo está configurando também o `advice mode` Proxy.

Após uma investigação mais aprofundada, encontramos o originador do modo de aviso Proxy, que é o `TransactionAutoConfiguration`, mais especificamente o`TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration.class`.

A aplicação da seguinte exclusão impediu que o `advice mode` **PROXY** fosse configurado em `TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector`, mas não estamos 100% certos de que isso não afetará a aplicação em algum momento:

```
@SpringBootApplication (exclude = TransactionAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Dado o fato de termos em nosso aplicativo apenas AspectJ configurado, e esta configuração está aplicando também Proxy, **existe uma maneira de validar qual modo está sendo usado durante uma transação**, e se possível, quais classes estão utilizando Proxy e quais estão usando AspectJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de tanto tempo esqueci até de responder.

Programaticamente **não encontrei nenhuma forma** para validar qual modo de transação está habilitado.

A única forma que encontramos para validar isso foi alterar o nível de log para as classes do Spring, e validar o pacote sendo logado durante as transações. Os pacotes de PROXY e ASPECT são diferentes, dessa forma conseguimos validar visualmente que a transação correta estava sendo utilizada.

Não é a melhor solução do mundo, é totalmente error-prone, e não achamos viável escrever um teste para validação da log em sí.

Por hora iremos aceitar esta solução mesmo, e quem sabe um dia voltaremos nesta questão.